# IOS CancelNotificaion on particular date when the app is in Background

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am working  on a application that reminds about the expiry date. I have implemented the same using `UILocalNotification` with repeat Interval `(NSMonthCalendarUnit, NSDayCalendarUnit,NSDayCalendarUnit)`. For example  I have the fire date on 01-01-2012 and the repeat interval is `NSDayCalendarUnit` and the end date is 12-12-2012, is it possbile to `cancelLocalNotification:` on expiry.

here is the code:-

```
- (void) scheduleNotificationOn:(NSDate*) fireDate
                       text:(NSString*) alertText
                     action:(NSString*) alertAction
                      sound:(NSString*) soundfileName
                launchImage:(NSString*) launchImage 
                    andInfo:(NSDictionary*) userInfo


{



userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            txtExpiryDate.text, @"ExpiryDate",
            txtRegNo.text , @"RegNo",
            nil];



UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];   
localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
localNotification.alertBody = alertText;
localNotification.alertAction = alertAction;    


NSLog(@"Repeat Type:%@",txtRepeat.text);

if([txtRepeat.text isEqualToString:@"Every Week"])
{

    NSLog(@"Every Week");
    localNotification.repeatInterval = 256;
}

else if([txtRepeat.text isEqualToString:@"Every Month"])
{
    NSLog(@"Every Month");
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMonthCalendarUnit;   
}

else if([txtRepeat.text isEqualToString:@"Every Day"])

{
    NSLog(@"Every Day");
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

}


if(soundfileName == nil)
{
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
}
else 
{
    localNotification.soundName = soundfileName;
}

NSLog(@"appDelegate.BadgeNumber:%d",appDelegate.BadgeNumber);

localNotification.alertLaunchImage = launchImage;
appDelegate.BadgeNumber = appDelegate.BadgeNumber + 1;
localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = appDelegate.BadgeNumber;    

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

[localNotification release];
}
```

I have worked by comparing current date to expiry date. But this work only if the app is in foreground and i cannot cancelnotification not background for a particular date. Please find the below code for the same:-

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
/*
 Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
 */
    BadgeNumber = 0;   
application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = BadgeNumber;



NSArray *localNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

NSLog(@"localNotifications Count %d",localNotifications.count);


for (UILocalNotification *notify in localNotifications)
{
    //notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    NSString *ExpiryDateString = [notify.userInfo objectForKey:@"ExpiryDate"];
    NSDate *ExpiryDate = [formatter dateFromString:ExpiryDateString];
    NSDate * NextFireDate = nil;
    NSLog(@"Expiry Date:%@",ExpiryDateString);

    if(notify.repeatInterval == NSDayCalendarUnit)
    {
        NSLog(@"Repeat Every Day");
        NextFireDate =  [[NSDate date] dateByAddingDays:1];
        NSLog(@"Next FireDate: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:NextFireDate]); 

    }
    if(notify.repeatInterval == NSWeekCalendarUnit)
    {
        NSLog(@"Repeat Every Day");
        NextFireDate =  [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:D_WEEK];
        NSLog(@"Next FireDate: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:NextFireDate]); 

    }
    if(notify.repeatInterval == NSMonthCalendarUnit)
    {
        NSLog(@"Repeat Every Day");
        //NextFireDate =  [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:D_Month];
        NextFireDate = [self CalculateExipiryDateForMonth];
        NSLog(@"Next FireDate: %@",[formatter stringFromDate:NextFireDate]); 

    }


    NSComparisonResult result = [NextFireDate compare:ExpiryDate];
    NSLog(@"NSComparisonResult:%d",result);

    if(result == NSOrderedDescending)
    {

        NSLog(@"Cancell......... Notification");
        NSLog(@"notify :::%@",notify);

    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Re-Schedule Notification");
        BadgeNumber =  BadgeNumber + 1;

        notify.applicationIconBadgeNumber = BadgeNumber;

        NSLog(@"BadgeNumber:%d",BadgeNumber);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notify];
    }
}


}



-(NSDate*) CalculateExipiryDateForMonth
{

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.month = 1;
NSDate *nextMonth = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
[components release];

NSDateComponents *nextMonthComponents = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:nextMonth];
NSDate *expiryDay = [gregorian dateFromComponents:nextMonthComponents];


NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dayComponent.day = -1;

NSDate *NewExpiry = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:expiryDay options:0];  



[gregorian release]; 
[dayComponent release];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSLog(@"Next Exipiry Date -----:%@",[formatter stringFromDate:NewExpiry]);


return NewExpiry;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, you cannot cancel a UILocalNotification while your app is running in the background.

Comment: I have scheduled UILocalNotification repeat interval NSDaycalendar. The notification should repeat everyday for 90 days and the 91st day it should get canceled. How to cancel the notification While the app is running not running is Foreground? Is there any specific property where we can set the last date of the UILocalnotification.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but it is not possible. There is no property that you can set. I looked into doing something similar to what you want to do for some time and couldn't find a solution. If you can find a solution I would love to hear it.

Comment: I can´t find any solution. What i do is, if when the notification is delivered to the app, i check if it still valid or not, then if it should expire, i cancel it and show a message to the user that this notification has been expired.

Answer (score 0):

```
                 **Apple RESPONSE:-**
```

I'm responding to your question about UILocalNotification.

At this time UILocalNotification does not have a way to specify an expiry
date or number of repetitions before the notification is automatically
canceled.

The closest you can get today is to schedule up to 64 individual
notifications instead of using the repeat interval.

But you're correct; if the user doesn't ever bring your app to the
foreground, it won't have the opportunity to cancel or reschedule local
notifications.

I highly recommend that you file an enhancement request at <
https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter> asking for this functionality in a
future release of iOS.

You also asked about what happens to local notifications when the user
removes your app from the device. iOS stores the local notifications so
that they are still scheduled if the user deletes and then reinstalls the
app.

When your app runs, it can check the scheduledLocalNotifications property
of UIApplication and remove any notifications that are no longer relevant.

Best regards,
--gc

---

Garth Cummings
Apple Developer Technical Support

Comment: also please put in the "enhancement reports"   that the app should also be able to decide at the time of the notification,  whether to let it display,  or suppress the notification....    seems obvious, but apparently not obvious enough...

Comment: by being able to run in background for 10 seconds to execute logic to decide whether the notification should go through.. and ontop of that,  to be able to register for an iOS notification,   so the app can make a decision to post notification because of an event that an app can be designed to work with...    for instance the notification of a pasteboard change...  (and to be able to decided with a quick routine by running in background for 10secs whether that needs to become a notification to the user)